# is there a way to refactor this? **kwarg - django

Tags: python, django, arguments, refactoring

I have been calling the same model over and over again but somethings with different field but there would be a few that would always be the same.  I am thinking if there is a way to refactor it?

For example.

```
def x(get_filter, **kwargs):
    # if blah 
    return User.object.get(is_active=True, is_deleted=False, is_staff=False, **kwargs)
    # if blah 
    return User.object.filter(is_active=True, is_deleted=False, is_staff=False, **kwargs)
    # if blah 
    return User.object.get(is_active=True, is_deleted=False, **kwargs)
    # if blah 
    return User.object.get(is_active=True, is_deleted=False, is_staff=False, is_superuser=True, **kwargs)
```

as can be seen, `is_active=True` and `is_deleted=False` is always being used.
I thought of doing something like

```
is_deleted = {'is_deleted': False}
is_active = {'is_active': True}
    User.object.filter( is_staff=False, **is_active, **is_deleted,**kwargs)
```

in my IDE, it would say duplicate ** is not allowed

Can someone give me an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, try this instead

```
options = {'is_deleted': False,
           'is_active': True}

kwargs.update(options)
User.object.filter(is_staff=False, **kwargs)
```

Comment: if for some reason that I want to override the `is_deleted` is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, you can override it after the update call using kwargs["is_deleted"] = True. Since it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3, this would indeed be allowed:

```
>>> def f(*a, **kwargs): pass
...
>>> a = {'a':1}
>>> b = {'b':2}
>>> f(**a, **b) # No problem!
```

Let us keep in mind, first of all, that `kwargs` is simply a dictionary: there is no magic about it. If you have default kwargs, you can put them in another (single!) dictionary:

```
additional_kwargs = {'is_deleted': False, 'is_active': True}
```

Now, we have two dictionaries, and it's a simple question of combining them: [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

We can do this in place:

```
kwargs.update(additional_kwargs)
```

And then call the function as normal:

```
User.object.filter(is_staff=False, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a new dictionary with the values you want based on your conditions and pass to filter. Se if something like this solves your problem:

```
should_delete = True if BLAH else False # your condition here
new_kwargs = dict(**kwargs, is_staff=False, is_deleted = should_delete)
return User.object.filter(**new_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's functool.partial

```
from functools import partial
def x(get_filter, **kwargs):
    common_invocation = partial(User.object.get, is_active=True, is_deleted=False)
    # if blah 
    return common_invocation(is_staff=False, **kwargs)
    # if blah 
    return User.object.filter(is_active=True, is_deleted=False, is_staff=False, **kwargs)
    # if blah 
    return common_invocation(**kwargs)
    # if blah 
    return common_invocation(is_staff=False, is_superuser=True, **kwargs)
```

I left your User.object.filter as such. You should get the idea from this.